# sonarqube dies right after I start it

Tags: postgresql, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

On CentOS-6 box, I am setting up sonarqube-6.4 with postgresql-9.3 Database server running on the same machine. I am using openJDK 8, version below:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

I only changed below properties which I think is sufficient to connect sonarqube web with postgre DB:

```
sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
sonar.jdbc.password=*****
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonarqube
sonar.web.host=0.0.0.0
sonar.web.port=9100
```

Now when I start sonar I see following in the sonar.log

```
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2017.06.07 01:53:47 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonar/temp
2017.06.07 01:53:47 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.JavaProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[es]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-0.b11.el6_9.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djna.nosys=true -XX:+
UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.Search
Server /opt/sonar/temp/sq-process5474669563516031830properties
2017.06.07 01:53:53 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
2017.06.07 01:53:53 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.JavaProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[web]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-0.b11.el6_9.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+H
eapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonar/lib/jdbc/postgresql/postgresql-9.4.1209.jre7.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /opt/sonar/temp/sq-process233758778210871240pro
perties
2017.06.07 01:53:57 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped
2017.06.07 01:53:57 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
2017.06.07 01:53:57 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Not sure why it dies.

Below is in the web.log:

```
2017.06.07 04:39:04 INFO  web[][o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonarqube
2017.06.07 04:39:04 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Web server startup failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not connect to database. Please check connectivity and settings (see the properties prefixed by 'sonar.jdbc.').
        at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.checkConnection(DefaultDatabase.java:108)
        at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:75)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$1.start(ComponentContainer.java:320)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1016)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:143)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel.start(PlatformLevel.java:88)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.start(Platform.java:231)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel1Container(Platform.java:190)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.init(Platform.java:86)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:43)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "127.0.0.1", user "sonar", database "sonarqube", SSL off)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
        at org.sonar.db.profiling.NullConnectionInterceptor.getConnection(NullConnectionInterceptor.java:31)
        at org.sonar.db.profiling.ProfiledDataSource.getConnection(ProfiledDataSource.java:323)
        at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.checkConnection(DefaultDatabase.java:106)
        ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "127.0.0.1", user "sonar", database "sonarqube", SSL off
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:451)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:223)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:211)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:407)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:275)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
        ... 35 common frames omitted
2017.06.07 04:39:06 INFO  web[][o.a.c.u.SessionIdGeneratorBase] Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [1,561] milliseconds.
2017.06.07 04:39:06 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[Scrier][[timer]]] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
 org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool$EstimatedTimeThread.run(ThreadPool.java:747)
```

Comment: Check log files under _sonar_install_dir/logs_ , especially _web.log_ as _web_ fails to start here. Then update your question with additional logs and what you actually tried to solve it.

Comment: Please tell me that's not your actually database password.

Comment: @NicolasB.-SonarSourceTeam, Issue is indeed in web.log, Is this the access/permission issue?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam, Yes that is my password. I am trying the Sonarqube.

Comment: Stacktrace says: _FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "127.0.0.1", user "sonar", database "sonarqube", SSL off_. Conclusion: You don't have permission to connect to PostgreSQL with IPV4 127.0.0.1 (localhost) in database sonarqube with role sonar. Check your [pg_hba](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

Comment: I've edited your password out of the question, but you should still reset it.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam, Ohh Thank you. I forgot to mask the password.

Comment: @michel.milezzi, Yes I updated the pq_hba.conf but the reload is also failing(fails to get the pid file somehow). I'll setup the postgre again from scratch.